# Does a mounted external NTFS drive (USB) need to be manually synced?

Tags: ntfs, external-hdd, sync, automount

To be clear, the terminology of "synced" that I'm using here might be incorrect.  I'm talking about the flushing through of the [write] cache.

I am `dd`ing a local drive image to a file on my external NTFS drive.

On a Windows system, an external NTFS drive takes a long time for the system to auto-write.  If I disconnect prematurely, data is lost.  It's never set up as a write-through cache.  I have to "ask it" to close properly.

Does Ubuntu have a short timeframe for auto-flushing, or do I need to specifically `umount` it before yanking out the cable?

Comment: Mint is off-topic.

Comment: @Pilot6, Mint is a direct Ubuntu inheritance. I also have Ubuntu desktops under my control which I have to also worry about similarly. Pedantic reasoning is of no help here.

Comment: Unmounting is necessary before disconnecting or powering down a disk drive. Umount will do a `sync` first, of course.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli, Thank you.  Does this happen automatically with a shutdown of the system, and is there a way to universally `mount` something with a forced sync after X seconds of write inactivity?  I don't want a fully synced "write though cache" style behavior; That is terribly time-expensive, but a short time-out (say 2 seconds) would increase the safety.

Comment: Mint is explicitly [off-topic](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic).  Only **official** flavors of Ubuntu are on topic on AskUbuntu.  There are countless derivatives of Ubuntu that are not supported by Canonical and are not on topic here.  Perhaps you can ask about this on Unix&Linux?

Comment: @Nmath, I'm really not in the mood for pedants today, sorry.  There is a Mint tag!  Here's what it says: *"For questions about Ubuntu that mention Linux Mint, an unofficial Ubuntu derivative. Questions not about Ubuntu but **only** Mint should not be asked here and will be closed as off-topic."*  My question was not only about Mint; I keep track of multiple installations, one of which is Ubuntu.  **But I shouldn't even have to explain that!**  I see the nonsense from Stackoverflow has finally invaded here.